# how to add style to form under echo statement by css

Tags: php, html, css

i want to style the form which is made in php by echo statement how to do that?? please help me

```
echo "<form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='result.php' class='form_style'>";
    .form_style input[type=submit] 
        {
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font: 15px;
            font-family:'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
            color: #fff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            background: #3d94f6;     
            text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
        }
```

Comment: remove `input[type=submit]` and it should work assuming `.form_style` is in a linked CSS file or in <style> tags.

Comment: Also, your `echo` statement is written incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should echo the CSS in the `<head>` of your document within the `<style></style>` tags

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        <?php echo ".form_style input[type=submit] 
        {
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font: 15px;
            font-family:'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
            color: #fff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            background: #3d94f6;     
            text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
        }"; ?>
    </style>
</head>
```

Although, if this isn't in need of being dynamic, I would just add the styles to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='result.php'   class='form_style'>";
echo "<style>.form_style input[type=submit]". 
    "{".
        "border: 0;".
        "border-radius: 2px;".
        "padding: 8px 16px;".
        "cursor: pointer;".
        "font: 15px;".
        "font-family:'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';".
        "color: #fff;".
        "text-transform: uppercase;".
        "background: #3d94f6;".     
        "text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);".
    "}</style>";
```